# Azure Java Web App with Application Insights showing 404 every 5 minutes

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-web-app-service

I have a Java Web App running in Azure Web App with Application Insights enabled and the javaagent configured in Application Settings.

In the insights, I see a 404 request to the web server (GET /) every 5 minutes, for which I do not have a handler (intentionally). The insights show no other dependencies involved and there is no Apache/Azure logs for the IP address of the culprit, but it seems it would be coming from the web app itself?

Is there a health check that is created automatically and how does one configure/disable it but keep the other insights like dependencies?

Java 8

Tomcat 8.5 (latest)

Spring Boot application

EDIT: I do not have the Spring Boot Actuator configured, for what its worth

Comment: Probably due to the always on setting of the web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be because you set Always On feature. If you don't have any webjob you can turn it off.

At least you can you can verify that by temporarily turning off Always On and verifying that those requests stop.

Also, as you know, you can see list of health checks in application insight.

Comment: Thanks, it does seem like this is the culprit. I'm still struggling to understand the scope of exactly what is "always on". Does this mean the tomcat container and related wars will be unavailable if idle for a period?

Comment: Azure unloads your site if it is idle for the standard 20 minute timeout, which can cause slow responses for the initial site users after it is unloaded. Enabling Always On essentially causes Azure to ensure that it remains in a running state.

Comment: After some more reading and testing, without Always On, the java process running tomcat will shut down. The next request must wait for tomcat to start, wars to deploy and then process the request. For future readers, this will create headaches when deploying to a staging slot that has shut down.

As an aside, you are supposed to be able to [set the application setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots#custom-warm-up) WEBSITE_SWAP_WARMUP_PING_PATH which you can point to a custom Controller, but I cannot seem to get this to work with Tomcat...

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, when Always On is off, the auto deploy still works as long as something is hitting the app service. One option for this is to use Availability tests from Application Insights to hit the url. I created a custom controller in my web app to handle those requests.